# How to correctly use clf.predict_proba?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My goal is to have the three most accurate predicted label.

By using this solution

```py
clf = svm.SVC(  
                kernel='rbf',
                C=51,
                gamma=1,
                probability=True
              ).fit(X,y)

predictions=[]
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as f:     
        clf = pickle.load(f)
for line in X:
        output=clf.predict(X)
          
        
#predictions.append(output)
df['prediction'] = output
# you add the list to the dataframe, then save the datframe to new csv

print(df)
```

I'm able to retrive the predicted label. However, when I add the `clf.predict_proba(X)` as follows

```py
clf = svm.SVC(  
                kernel='rbf',
                C=51,
                gamma=1,
                probability=True
              ).fit(X,y)

predictions=[]
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as f:     
        clf = pickle.load(f)
for line in X:
        output=clf.predict(X)
        output_prob=clf.predict_proba(X)  
        
#predictions.append(output)
df['prediction'] = output
# you add the list to the dataframe, then save the datframe to new csv

print(df)
```

I'm having the following error:

```
AttributeError: predict_proba is not available when  probability=False
```

According to the Scikit [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) the probability as True should be defined explicitly as I did in

```py
clf = svm.SVC(  
                kernel='rbf',
                C=51,
                gamma=1,
                probability=True
              ).fit(X,y)
```

How to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: But you overwrite your model with one from a pickle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below overwrites your clf variable with the model loaded from pickle file which probably its probability attribute is False.

```
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as f:     
        clf = pickle.load(f)
```

So you are not using the SVC instance you've created at the first part of your code.

According to [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) probability must be enabled prior to calling fit, so you can't change it in the model loaded from pickle file.

You have to either use your own trained model (the one you created and called fit on) or use another pretrained model(loaded from pickle file) with proabiblity attribute enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the script `train.py` which I used to train the model by adding the `probability=True` as follows:

```py
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf',
              C=51,
              gamma=1,
              probability=True
              )
```

Then I have updated the script `prediction.py` which I used to make predictions according your suggestions:

```py
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as f:     
        clf = pickle.load(f)
```

Now it works